# Software utility to send an email when a file's size starts getting too big?

Tags: windows, email, notifications

Is there a utility that you can set up to watch a file, (meaning that the software tells the OS that it wants to notified when the file is written to) and send a notification email when the file reaches a certain size?

Comment: I see many commercial utilities that can do this, and am sure free ones exist as well. This is also something that should be possible to do using a quick 'n' dirty script, periodically run by the OS' scheduler. If you want a specific answer, you'll need to tell us which OS you use (a Windows PS script can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/candede/archive/2010/01/14/monitor-file-size.aspx)

Comment: @Karan That's good for now, but it doesn't "watch" a file, it checks it at a specified interval.  Watching it means more of subscribing to an event that is fired off when the file is modified, which sends a message containing the new file size to the script.